# Original raster is rotated after processing in ArcGIS without reprojection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, pansharpening

I have a regular TIF raster with georeferencing stored as .wld and .prj files. The raster itself has horizontal orientation (see pic.1), although after being opened in ArcGIS it becomes rotated due to projection information (see. pic2.).

The problem is that after applying [pan-sharpening](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-pansharpened-raster-dataset.htm) in ArcGIS (without any reprojection) the output becomes a GeoTIFF with this rotation fixed in raster. So this procedure adds unwanted rotation (see pic 2.) into original raster and I cannot process it further in other software.

The question is: is there any way to output result raster not as GeoTIFF but as regular TIF with .wld and .prj files, like it was before (see pic. 1), to keep an original alignment?

[image: pic 1]
pic 1.

[image]
pic 2.